# Unable to get mysql to recognise query using in statement

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been attempting to adjust a mysql SELECT statement based on input from checkboxes. The php code collects the ticked checkboxes into an array, implodes them into a comma-separated list and then runs the query using an in statement (as was detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3084520)).

The query generated comes out as `SELECT * FROM events WHERE Discipline IN (SJ,OTHER)` which is a correctly formatted query as far as I can tell.

This shows up as an invalid query when run from the php code. When I run the query using phpmyadmin, I receive this message:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'SJ' in 'where clause'
```

I was wondering if anyone could tell my why that query is generating the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting quotes around the values in the IN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE Discipline IN ('SJ','OTHER')
```

Comment: That works for the query.
Unfortunately, I now have to persuade the php code to wrap the strings in quotes before imploding them into a comma separated list.

Answer (score 0):

If SJ and OTHER are string literal use:

```
 SELECT * FROM events WHERE Discipline IN ('SJ','OTHER')
```